# Preg_replace <br> one time only before the first letter / word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I know how to replace a first occurrence of a `<br>`. For instance:

```php
$text = preg_replace('/<br>/','',$text,1);
```

However, I need to remove the first `<br>` once **only before the first letter / word**.

Remove if:

```
<br>
A storm is coming...
```

Do not remove if (even though it's a first occurrence):

```
A storm is coming...
<br>
```

Comment: try `$text = preg_replace('/<br>(?=\s*\w)/','',$text,1);`

Comment: What "letter/word" do you mean? Can that be `Ő`?

Comment: why not use `$text = preg_replace('/^(\r|\t|\n|\s)*<br>/g','',$text);` ?

Comment: @stribizhev By "first letter" I meant something like A, I (A car, I am).

Comment: @morels can you explain what that exactly does? Is it: if a new line / tab remove `<br>`?

Comment: Then Avinash already posted a viable solution.

Comment: @morels Your example worked.

Comment: @user5489021 nice to be helpful. posted the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a positive lookahead assertion to check whether the `<br>` is followed by a word character or not.

```
$text = preg_replace('/<br>(?=\s*\w)/','',$text,1);
```

or

```
$text = preg_replace('/<br>(?=\s*[a-z])/i','',$text,1);
```

Comment: I don't if it's the specificity of my page but only @morels example worked, which was `$text = preg_replace('/^(\r|\t|\n|\s)*<br>/g','',$text);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `$text = preg_replace('/^(\r|\t|\n|\s)*<br>/g','',$text);` ?

If the string starts with 0 or more carriage returns/spaces/tabs followed by a `<br>` it removes the `<br>`.

It is like a string trim plus a `<br>` remover. More efficient than a simple `<br>` remover done like `preg_replace('/^<br>*/g','',$text)`

Comment: tipically g stands for 'global' i.e. it analyzes all the input string. In your case it is optional, because you need to match only the first occurrence.

Comment: Anyway if the answer is functioning for your problem you are pleased to accept the answer and close the topic. If you need more specific answer you are pleased to be more specific in questions and comments as well.